# COMPARE THE AVERAGE LENGTH OF THE TWO CONFIDENCE INTERVALS

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, confidence-interval, expected-value

Question 14 page 399 - Mood Graybill and Boes (1974):

> In sampling from a normal population compare the average length of the two
>   confidence intervals for the mean $\mu$. when (a) $\sigma$ is known and (b) $\sigma$ is unknown.

I know a) 
$$IC_\gamma\left(\mu\right)=\left(\bar{X}-z_{\frac{1+\gamma}{2}}\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}},\bar{X}+z_{\frac{1+\gamma}{2}}\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}\right)$$

And b) $$IC_\gamma\left(\mu\right)=\left(\bar{X}-t_{\left(n-1;\frac{1+\gamma}{2}\right)}\frac{S}{\sqrt{n}},\bar{X}+t_{\left(n-1;\frac{1+\gamma}{2}\right)}\frac{S}{\sqrt{n}}\right)$$

$$E\left[l\left(I_1\right) \right]=2z_{\frac{1+\gamma}{2}}\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$$

$$E\left[l\left(I_2\right) \right] =\frac{2t_{\left(n-1;\frac{1+\gamma}{2}\right)}}{\sqrt{n}}\sqrt{\frac{2}{n-1}}\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n-1}{2}\right)}\sigma$$

$$\frac{E\left[l\left(I_2\right) \right]}{E\left[l\left(I_1\right) \right]}=\frac{t_{\left(n-1;\frac{1+\gamma}{2}\right)}}{z_{\frac{1+\gamma}{2}}}\sqrt{\frac{2}{n-1}}\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n-1}{2}\right)}$$

Any idea? How I can prove $\frac{E\left[l\left(I_2\right) \right]}{E\left[l\left(I_1\right) \right]}>1$ or $\frac{E\left[l\left(I_2\right) \right]}{E\left[l\left(I_1\right) \right]}<1$?

Comment: As this is a textbook question you need to include the self-study tag.